# How do I avoid Facebook adding _escaped_fragment_ to urls in Facebook comments notifications?

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments, hashbang

I have an Angular site that uses hashbang (#!) in urls. To render these pages for crawlers and Facebook bot (who changes the #! to ?_escaped_fragment) I have server side logic to add meta-tags, open graph tags etc and render a special version of the page.

I.e: http://example.com/something/#!/a/special/url is fetched by Facebook using http://example.com/something/?_escaped_fragment_=/a/special/url and my server responds correctly.

This works great. Facebook's own open graph debug page fetches the page meta data correctly. And I am able to share the page on Facebook.

But the pages also have Facebook comments. It is added by the javascript which inserts

```
<div class="fb-comments fb_iframe_widget fb_iframe_widget_fluid" 
  data-href="http://example.com/something/#!/a/special/url" 
  data-numposts="5" 
  data-width="100%" 
  data-version="v2.3" 
  data-colorscheme="light"
</div>
```

The comment box is shown and all is good. I can even post comments and see them later.

BUT: When Facebook sends notifications to other users that have commented, the link displayed on Facebook has a ?_escaped_fragment_ and not a hashbang (#!) resulting in the user getting the "special" Facebook page. This is strange to me since the escaped fragment is supposed to only be used by bots, not when displayed in links.

The link on facebook notifications is on this format `lsr.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsomething%2F%3F_escaped_fragment_%3D%a%252Fspecial%252Furl%252F17%252F&ext=......`

Is there some way to avoid Facebook displaying this _escaped_fragment_ when displaying the link?

Comment: Have you considered not relying on the presence of `_escaped_fragment_` and instead using the user-agent of the crawler to identify if it is FB or not? The UA string is documented here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler